# By batch, how can I run a for-loop for a R script?

Tags: r, batch-file, for-loop

Now I have 10 data sets for example named by `out1sim.txt, out2sim.txt ... out10sim.txt` .

My R script is a function that can load each data set and output `out1.Rdata, out2.Rdata ... out10.Rdata`.

Let's say the R script is test.R

How can I loop the function by batch? I mean when I do for-loop, how can I point the variable `i` into R script?

like in batch, I can do loop like this

```
for i in {1,10}
do # here I want to point this i into R script to make it load outisim.data and output outi.Rdata.
```

How can I do that? (by the way, my R code already has the function that load `outisim.data` and output `outi.Rdata`. I just want to know how to point `i` into R script.)

done

Comment: could you provide an example of the code you seek in any other programming language? Would help me be sure of how to answer.

Comment: It's unclear when you say "point i into R script", can you clarify? You want to save it, access it, print it?

Comment: You need to write your function so that it *expects* `i` (or some other argument - the actual name of the file would be a better choice), you can't just force it in externally.

Answer (score 0):

Create a vector of your input file names.

```
file_n <- c("out1sim.txt", ..., "out10sim.txt")
for (i in 1:length(file_n)) {
    infile <- read.table(file_n[i], sep="\t")
    save(infile, file=paste0(out[i], ".RData"))
}
```

Comment: I made some corrections... not sure why you used `c` as a loop index but never referred to it and chose to manually increment `i`. You don't need to initialize the looping index either. Also added a missing `"` and made it so the file index would work for reading in data. And `infile` *would* need to be initialized if you just start assigning to a particular index. Just got rid of the index since it doesn't seem like all the files need to be kept in R's memory.

Comment: Thanks Gregor35.  I did butcher that.  I was modifying other code of mine.  Forgot some stuff.